# Ruby on Rails - js stops working on js.erb file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have one view. In this view I want to paginate with AJAX 4 different things. I got 2 of them working. And when I added the third (doing the same method as the others) the previous 2 stopped working. Gonna paste some code for you guys to understand.

The view for the 2 paginations working with AJAX:

```
<div id="ofertas"><%= render "ofertas_ajax" %></div>
```

this renders a partial with a normal loop through the colletion of items and the will paginate links. all fine.

the other that is working is this:

```
<div id="historico"><%= render "historico_ajax" %></div>
```

this renders a partial just as the other above.

My application.js for these 2:

```
$(document).on("click","#ofertas .pagination a",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.getScript(this.href);
});

$(document).on("click","#historico .pagination a", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.getScript(this.href);
});
```

My `home.js.erb` because all these divs are in the `home.html.erb` view

```
$("#ofertas").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("ofertas_ajax")) %>");

$("#historico").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("historico_ajax")) %>");
```

OK - So this works fine. At least testing it I see no issue and it paginates properly with AJAX.

And I added this div for the 3rd pagination:

```
<div id="candidaturass"><%= render "candidaturaspag" %></div>
```

which again renders a normal partial with a normal loop and the correct will paginate links

I added this in `application.js`

```
$(document).on("click","#candidaturass .pagination a",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.getScript(this.href);
});
```

again similar to the others. and of course I added this in the `home.js.erb` file:

```
$("#candidaturass").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("candidaturaspag")) %>");
```

Now all the paginations don't work. after I add this line. I somehow think my `home.js.erb` file shouldn't look like this:

```
$("#ofertas").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("ofertas_ajax")) %>");

$("#historico").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("historico_ajax")) %>");

$("#candidaturass").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("candidaturaspag")) %>");
```

but then again I really don't know why it doesn't work. And if my file is properly coded.

Can someone help?

Comment: Tip: if you go into your browser's developer tools, go to the Network tab, click one of your Ajax links on the page, then copy response from the network tab and paste it into your console, it should tell you about any errors the scripts are causing (scripts that are retrieved from the server don't show errors when jQuery `eval`s them). I'm not sure why you have the response for all 3 of your separate links in the same template though, shouldn't they be in 3 different templates (and probably rendered by 3 different actions?), or else each link is gonna do exactly the same thing.

Comment: I just get 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: If you get a 500 Internal Server Error, take a look at your log files.  There might be a typo or other coding error in one of your partials.

Comment: I've been trying for 2 days. I really don't know

Comment: everything is correctly spelled. Done the same way as the others,.

Comment: of course. downvote and no reason stated.

Comment: Are there any js errors on the page? check the js console?

Comment: If you get a 500 error, it means that your code is throwing an exception somewhere. If you could edit your question and post the relevant portion of your log (where you see the error), would be really helpful for us to detect the problem.

Comment: Can you post any errors you're getting, both on the rails console, but also on your js console? (Google Chrome gives you a js console for free)

Answer (score 1):

try this...be careful while rendering in js.erb...quotes should be taken care of:-

try to follow this:-

```
##adding single quotes   
$("#ofertas").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('ofertas_ajax')) %>");

$("#historico").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('historico_ajax')) %>");

$("#candidaturass").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('candidaturaspag')) %>");
```

**above partials will only work if they are reqular partials else yo have to explicitly specify users/_partial_name or something else that you want**